# Efficient cleaning of missing value in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, data-cleaning

```
require (data.table)
dat1 <- fread('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/primary-tumor/primary-tumor.data',stringsAsFactors=T)
```

I would like to replace the `?` and missing values with the most frequent value per column and make them `factor` (for `RandomForest`).
I tried to omit the `?` from dat1$V4:

```
> dat2=subset(dat1, dat1$V4!='?')
Error in `[.data.table`(x, r, vars, with = FALSE) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 339 but there are 184 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
```

And afterwards in case of success to use for make all the `dataframe` columns `factor`:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(lapply(dat1, as.factor))
```

Here is the header of `dat1`:

```
> head (dat1)
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
1:  1  1  1  ?  3  2  2  1  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2:  1  1  1  ?  3  2  2  2  2   2   1   2   2   2   1   2   1   2
3:  1  1  2  2  3  1  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   2
4:  1  1  2  ?  3  1  2  1  1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   2
5:  1  1  2  ?  3  1  2  1  1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   2
6:  1  1  2  ?  3  1  2  2  2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   1   2
```

Here is the `str(dat1)`:

```
> str (dat1)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  339 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ V1 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V2 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V3 : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","?": 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V4 : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","?": 4 4 2 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V5 : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","?": 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ V6 : int  2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ V7 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V8 : int  1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V9 : int  2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V10: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V11: int  2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V12: int  2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V13: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","?": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 3 ...
 $ V14: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ V15: int  2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ V16: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","?": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V17: int  2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V18: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Don't use the dataframe name in `subset(dat1, V4 != '?')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's kind "hacky" this should get you there. I didn't see any NA in your data.frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat1 <- read.table('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/primary-tumor/primary-tumor.data',stringsAsFactors=T, sep = ",")

dat1 <- sapply(dat1, as.character)
temp <- list()

for (i in 1:ncol(dat1)){
  temp[i] <- data.frame(str_replace(dat1[,i], "[?]",names(sort(table(dat1[,i]), 
decreasing = T))[1]))

}
dat2 <- bind_cols(temp)
colnames(dat2) <- colnames(dat1)
```

Comment: Edited. Should have been `temp <- list()`

Answer (score 1):

The following function replaces all `NA` and `'?'` values by the most frequent column value. Then it's just a matter of `lapply`ing it to the data.frame.

```
mostFreq <- function(x, na = '?'){
  i <- is.na(x) | x %in% na
  tbl <- table(x[!i])
  x[i] <- names(tbl)[which.max(tbl)]
  if(is.factor(x)) x <- droplevels(x)
  x
}

# Before    
as.list(dat1[1:20, 1:3])
#$V1
# [1] "1" "?" "2" "?" "2" NA  "?" "?" "2" "?" "?" "?" NA  NA 
#[15] NA  NA  "?" "2" "2" "2"
#
#$V2
# [1] "1" "3" "2" "3" "1" "2" "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "1" "?" NA 
#[15] "?" "3" "1" NA  "?" "1"
#
#$V3
# [1] "?" "1" "?" "3" "1" NA  NA  "3" "1" "1" "1" "2" NA  NA 
#[15] NA  NA  "?" "?" NA  "2"

# After
lapply(dat1[1:20, 1:3], mostFreq)
#$V1
# [1] "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2"
#[15] "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2"
#
#$V2
# [1] "1" "3" "2" "3" "1" "2" "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1"
#[15] "1" "3" "1" "1" "1" "1"
#
#$V3
# [1] "1" "1" "1" "3" "1" "1" "1" "3" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1"
#[15] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2"
```

And change the entire dataframe.

```
dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, mostFreq)
```

And to coerce to class `factor`:

```
dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, factor)
```

**Edit.**

The function above can be simplified if you read the data setting `na.strings = '?'` to start with.

```
dat1 <- fread(<URI>, na.strings = '?', <other args>)
```

Then use the function below where there was the original `mostFreq`.

```
mostFreq2 <- function(x){
  tbl <- table(x, useNA = "no")
  x[is.na(x)] <- names(tbl)[which.max(tbl)]
  x
}
```

**Test data.**

Since you have not posted an example dataset, I will create one similar to what the question describes.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
n <- 300
x <- replicate(6, sample(c(NA, '?', 1:2), n, TRUE))
y <- replicate(6, sample(c(NA, '?', 1:3), n, TRUE))
dat1 <- cbind.data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat1 <- dat1[, sample(ncol(dat1))]
names(dat1) <- paste0('V', 1:12)
str(dat1)
```

Comment: You can simplify this if you use the parameter `na.strings` from `fread`.  Then no need to use `i` nor `drop.levels`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You are right, I was assuming that the OP wanted to clean the data and completely forgot about `na.strings`. Thanks. As for `stringsAsFactors`, it's in the data creation code.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas after defining the mostFreq,  I use dat2<-lapply(dat1, mostFreq) and dat3 <- data.frame(lapply(dat2, as.factor)). I get MANY values for the factor. How can I handle it?

Comment: @Avi What do you mean by *MANY*?